# Boost ( 1.34) Regex syntax bug

Tags: regex, boost, c++11, boost-regex

I have read some amount of documentation, and I am more familiar with the current version being shipped with VS2010. But for now I am stuck with ubuntu 8.04, and boost 1.34 and am getting some weird sort of error. Can anybody tell what I am doing wrong. Here is the man page for [regex_search boost v1.34](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_1/libs/regex/doc/regex_search.html)

Here is what I am doing in my code :

```
std::string sLine;
getline(dataFile, sLine);
boost::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> lineSmatch; 
boost::match_flag_type regFlags = boost::match_default;    
boost::regex finalRegex(linePattern);

boost::regex_search(sLine.begin(), sLine.end(), lineSmatch, finalRegex, regFlags);
```

---

Here is the compilation error:

error: no matching function for call to 'regex_search(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator, std::allocator > >, std::allocator, std::allocator > > > > >&, boost::regex&, boost::regex_constants::match_flag_type&)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to apply `regex_search` to `sLine` itself instead of
`iterator` range, as *Howard* answered, you can use `sLine` instead of
`begin()` and `end()`.
For example:

```
boost::regex_search(sLine, lineSmatch, finalRegex, regFlags);
```

If you have to give `iterator` range to `regex_search`, since the type
argument for `match_results` is `const_iterator`, the first and second
arguments for `regex_search` need to be `const_iterator` too.
For example:

```
std::string::const_iterator b = sLine.begin(), e = sLine.end();
boost::regex_search(b, e, lineSmatch, finalRegex, regFlags);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Can't help you specifically with ubuntu 8.04, and boost 1.34.  However the following compiles for me on [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) which implements C++11.  Perhaps it is close enough to your environment to tell you what is wrong.

```
#include <regex>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream dataFile;
    std::string sLine, linePattern;
    getline(dataFile, sLine);
    std::match_results<std::string::const_iterator> lineSmatch; 
    std::regex_constants::match_flag_type regFlags = 
                                        std::regex_constants::match_default;    
    std::regex finalRegex(linePattern);

    std::regex_search(sLine, lineSmatch, finalRegex, regFlags);
}
```